# Adding Custom Input to WooCommerce Product Page, Add to Cart Form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding custom inputs to WooCommerce's Product Page to Add to Cart form.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'inputForm');

function inputForm()
{
   echo '<input name="test[0][foo]" type="text" />';
   echo '<input name="test[0][bar]" type="text" />';
}
```

However unfortunately when I add a product to cart, I can't see this inputs nor their values anywhere.

I'd like to be able to see;

1. In Cart view page, under the item.
2. I'd like to be able to see them under Order Details in Admin Panel.

Is there any up-to-date way of doing this?

Comment: What ways have you tried? This question comes up frequently here. Here's a basic [tutorial](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-product/) that I wrote. If you want something more complex I highly recommend springing for [Product Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: thank you @helgatheviking it was really helpful. I for the moment only problem I have is to be able to view these additional fields within WP Admin / Order Details.

Comment: That is covered under my tutorial.